# wordpress in subdirectory beside my website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a website like www.example.com that already i created(none wordpress).
now i install a wordpress on subdirectory.wordpress file is in www.example.com/test/file and www.example.com/test is wordpress address(i edit its in General Settings).
and i copy .htaccess and index.php to example.com/test
index.php in example.com/test

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/file/wp-blog-header.php' );`

index.php in example.com/test/file

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

.htaccess in both address:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in root example.com

```
 RewriteOptions inherit
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
 RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/index\.php\/asd" [R=301,L]
```

and whem i want to go www.example.com/test it redirect to www.example.com
how i fix it?

Comment: Why don't you put your WordPress install files directly in the `test` subdirectory?

Comment: In `/test/.htaccess`, you don't need to prefix the last substitution with `/test/`, you're already using it for your `RewriteBase`.